# Execute query in function or not

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to process a text column (one of several columns) in a database table with tens of thousands of rows. The output will be a substring (found with a regular expression) of the text column, for each row. Which of the following two approaches should I use:

1. `SELECT function1();` in which the function itself runs the `SELECT` and then processes the text column.
2. `SELECT function2(value) from table1, table2, ... where ...;` in which only the text column is passed to the function for processing.

This will be run on PostgreSQL 8.4.

Comment: what do you have in function1() ?

Comment: 1 st type will serve always the same based on your query written inside the function.
2 nd type is like generic the output will varry based on the parameter value you pass...

Comment: @logan: That function would execute a query similar to (2), and the process the text column. The point is that the function executes the query itself, rather than processing a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd query : the query will call function for each every row it returns. whereas first query just calls the function only once..

It depends on what content you have in function to say which is efficient ! It will be meaning full question if you have given what the function content is !

Comment: I haven't written the functions yet, because that depends on which approach I should take :)

Comment: fine.. if you want to apply function on each data column of all rows then go with option 2; else option 1